# Function name expected on closure

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
for(var i = 0; i <=3; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var j = i;
        function(){
            console.log(j);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

I am getting an error 'Function name expected' on the second function. I don't understand why I can't use an anonymous function here.

Comment: OP, are you expecting the working code to log 0-3 one second after the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a closure and call it right away do this:

```
(function(){
  console.log(j);
}());
```

But, to actually capture the `i` correctly for the inner function, you can move the function up a bit and pass it `i`:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  (function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i);
    }, 1000);}(i));
}
```

And, to actually print the numbers 1 second after each other, you can do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  (function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i);
    }, 1000*(i+1));}(i));
}
```

Comment: While this solves the immediate issue the OP will get `4` as the output for each timeout. I know that wasn't the question asked, but you might as well shoot for the home run :)

Comment: That helped a lot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jordão's answer, I ended up using the following code:

```
for(var i = 0; i <=3; i++){ 
    (function(){
        var j = i;
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(j);
        }, 1000);
    }());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you know for the future you can get your output with a smaller (and cleaner?) number of lines of code if you use recursion:

```
function loop(i) {
  console.log(i = i || 0);
  if (i <= 3) setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++i);
}

loop();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/byv2zv90/)